# Python parse JSON sheets find values and increment counters

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to find a solution here and in a bit of a rush otherwise, I'd post more of a solution but the premise is..

I'm trying to use Python to parse JSON sheets which contain a time of an incident along with the name of an incident. Each time a specific "name" appears I'd like it's relative counter to increment by 1 for that DATE - So I can count the times the incident occurred per DAY (don't care about minutes). There are also several JSON files in a single folder I'd like to iterate through. *.json

An exmaple of the JSON is:

```
{
  "logs" : [ {
    "other" : "xVKNXCVNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:50.412Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Alpha Beta: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }]
}
```

So for this instance, the results would be:

```
"Alpha Beta: Bingo": 1 for 2017-06-15
"Terra Zaba: Bingo": 2 for 2017-06-15
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried ? And fix your JSON data in your question it's not a valid JSON neither a valid Python data.

Comment: Thanks @ChihebNexus - That JSON is automatically output from an application I'm receiving it from. I'll be sure to fix it as per your helpful recommendations. Thanks for the down vote too.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. howver you can use `json.loads()` and it'll load your JSON into a python dict.

Answer (score 0):

First you need re-format the JSON data, you provided at here include some error.

For answer the question, I had format the JSON file as below.

```
{
  "logs" : [ {
    "other" : "xVKNXCVNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:50.412Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Alpha Beta: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-1T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }]
}
```

After format the JSON file, I can try to answer the question.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

PATH = r"E:\temp\temp.json"

def parse_func(f):
    """
    parse the JSON file
    :param f: the parsed file path
    :return: the result dict
    """
    parse_Dict = dict()
    parse_List = list()
    num_Dict = dict()

    # load the JSON data to `data `
    with open(f) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    # parse the "name " and the "time "
    for i in range(0, len(data["logs"])):
        parse_List.append(data["logs"][i]["name"])
        parse_List.append(data["logs"][i]["time"].split("T")[0])

    print(parse_List)

    # change the list to the dict
    for ii in range(0, len(parse_List), 2):
        # the "name " and the "time "
        parse_Dict[parse_List[ii]] = parse_List[ii + 1]

        # the "name " and the "retry number "
        if parse_List[ii] not in num_Dict:
            num_Dict[parse_List[ii]] = 1
        else:
            num_Dict[parse_List[ii]] = num_Dict[parse_List[ii]] + 1
    print(parse_Dict)
    print(num_Dict)

    # format the result_Dict
    result_Dict = dict()
    for k in parse_Dict.keys():
        result_Dict[k] = "%d for %s" % (num_Dict[k], parse_Dict[k])

    print(result_Dict)

parse_func(PATH)
```

The code output is,

```
['Alpha Beta: Bingo', '2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo', '2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo', '2017-06-15']
{'Alpha Beta: Bingo': '2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo': '2017-06-15'}
{'Alpha Beta: Bingo': 1, 'Terra Zaba: Bingo': 2}
{'Alpha Beta: Bingo': '1 for 2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo': '2 for 2017-06-15'}
```

When write the code I found a question, need you judge for yourself.

Because the keys in the `dict()` need unique, when a element with the same `name` , but had different `time`. how to record.

For example, if I change the JSON file.

```
{
  "logs" : [ {
    "other" : "xVKNXCVNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:50.412Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Alpha Beta: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2017-06-15T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }, {
    "other" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "time" : "2016-06-1T01:31:37.229Z",
    "other2" : "xVKxXCbNsk",
    "name" : "Terra Zaba: Bingo"
  }]
}
```

**Note** `"time" : "2016-06-1T01:31:37.229Z",` line had changed.

The output will change to

```
['Alpha Beta: Bingo', '2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo', '2017-06-15', 'Terra Zaba: Bingo', '2016-06-1']
{'Terra Zaba: Bingo': '2016-06-1', 'Alpha Beta: Bingo': '2017-06-15'}
{'Terra Zaba: Bingo': 2, 'Alpha Beta: Bingo': 1}
{'Terra Zaba: Bingo': '2 for 2016-06-1', 'Alpha Beta: Bingo': '1 for 2017-06-15'}
```

**Note** please check the different with the above one.